# jquery help is required for z-index

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

at following link i've placed some jquery script.
[www.onemileaway.com/test3/cirle.html](http://www.onemileaway.com/test3/cirle.html)
i've added pie.htc to make circles.

what i'm doing here is to rollover 5 circle to change background color and upon click it keep the color of rollover effect.

when i click on first circle and now rollover on second one its not applying z-index:1000. as i've applied it in .hover effect.

please understand and hlep me.

code can be viewed by viewsource.

thank you

Comment: `code can be viewed by viewsource.` That's not very polite. You want people to help you but you're basically saying `I'm too lazy to post relevant code, so find it yourself!`

Answer (score 4):

Look at your javascript console, you'll notice you have a problem loading your jquery library.

Comment: thats worked pretty well.